# Evaluating intervention statistics for a given observation

Tags: r, intervention-analysis

My desired procedure is the following:

1. A time series is imported.
2. One or more observations are flagged as events/outliers.
3. An automated procedure determines what type of outlier each event is and its impact (or possibly says that there are no visible outlier effects at that/those observation/s).
4. A revised time series is given, with the outliers de-effected.

I am aware of several `R` packages that deal with outliers, however, most of them either automatically detect outliers or require you to provide all the outlier statistics. Is there a ready-made solution for this in some package, and if not, how should I go about writing my own solution?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Forecasting Systems has a software called Autobox that delivers a cleansed dataset free of outliers.  It tells you the type of each of the outliers in the equation and also a report.  the Swiss government uses Autobox for data cleansing. http://bit.ly/28JZIXz

We report out 6 types

1)Outliers
2-6)changes in level, trend, seasonality, parameters, variance.

We have a Windows and an R version(not CRAN).

Post an example dataset and we can post results.

I am part of this company.